# Remove spacing between views in NativeScript

Tags: angular, telerik, nativescript

i have buttons inside a stacklayout, but by default it adds spacing between child views. How can i remove that ?

```
    <ScrollView orientation="horizontal" (scroll)="onScroll($event)" id="mainScrollViewButtons" row="0">
        <StackLayout id="mainButtonBox" orientation="horizontal">
            <Button class="btn btn-primary" margin="0" marginLeft="0" marginRight="0" width="120" text="Blue" (tap)="onBlue()"  (swipe)="onSwipe($event)"></Button>
            <Button class="btn btn-primary" margin="0" marginLeft="0" marginRight="0" width="120" text="Purple" (tap)="onPurple()" (swipe)="onSwipe($event)"></Button>
            <Button class="btn btn-primary" margin="0" width="150" text="Yellow" (tap)="onYellow()" (swipe)="onSwipe($event)"></Button>
            <Button class="btn btn-primary" margin="0" width="120" text="Red" (tap)="onYellow()" (swipe)="onSwipe($event)"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following "hack"

in your app.css

```
Button {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.0);
  border-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.0);
  border-width: 1;
}
```

Discussion about explaining the issue behind the button borders can be found [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2626)

Comment: It looses the ripple effect. I tried to put `Label`. it has the same result as this solution

Comment: Yes, it will certainly lose the ripple effect as this is coming from the default background of the button in Android. This is a common issue in native Android as well so the solution is to provide your own ripple effect. In nativescript there is a plugin for that matter called nativescript-ripple

Comment: does it has support for nativescript-angular ?